# What is a simple, convincing argument why product of topologies $\mathfrak{T} \times \mathfrak{T}$ is a basis instead of a topology?

Tags: general-topology

For instance, let $(\mathbb{R}, \mathfrak{T})$ be $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology.

Why is that $\mathfrak{T} \times \mathfrak{T}$ is a basis on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ instead of topology?

It seems that people just take $\mathfrak{T} \times \mathfrak{T}$ as a basis by definition. There must be some open sets in the product that cannot be represented by Cartesian product of $\mathfrak{T} \times \mathfrak{T}$, but I don't have any examples handy.

Can someone please instruct?

*I am still not convinced because the examples so far are not "constructive" :(*

Comment: An open triangle is not an element of the product

Comment: What do you mean that the examples are not "constructive"? Are you unable to show that the unit ball is not a product of two sets from $\mathbb R$?

Comment: It is a basis *by definition* and simply fails to be a topology (in almost all cases). Not constructive? Just like @5xum I don't understand what lacks in the examples.

Comment: For example $[(0,1)\times(0,1)]\cup[(1,2)\times(1,2)]$ cannot be written as $A\times B$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: If I take the union of two elements of $\mathcal I\times\mathcal  I$ (boxes), it is very unlikely that their union will be a box. So $I\times I$ will not be topology).

Since you want an explicit construction, take the union of the sets $A=(0,1)\times(0,1)$ and $B=(1,2)\times(1,2)$. This is not of the form $I\times J$ for any open sets $I$ and $J$ in $\mathbb R$ because if there were, then $I$ would have to contain $1/2$ and $J$ would have to contain $3/2$ but the point $(1/2,3/2)$ is not in $A\cup B$.

Answer (score 4):

The unit ball $$\{(x,y)| x^2+y^2<1\}$$ is not a cartesian product of two sets in $\mathbb R$, but it is an open set in $\mathbb R^2$.

This can easily be shown using basic set theory - you don't need any knowledge of topology. If you find it hard to show this fact, then it's good practice and I suggest you try to do it!

Answer (score 1):

If $X=(|X|,\tau)$ denotes a topological space with underlying set $|X|$ and topology $\tau$ then the collection $\tau\times\tau:=\{U\times V\mid U,V\in\tau\}$ **is by definition** a [base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)#Definition_and_basic_properties) for a topology on set $|X|\times|X|$ so that arguments cannot play any role in this.

It is evident that the collection covers the set and that it is closed under finite intersections.

That's why "people just take $\tau \times \tau$ as a basis by definition".

Is it also a topology?

For that it must also be closed under arbitrary unions. To come to the answer "no" in an informal sense it is enough allready to find two squares (sets $U\times U\in\tau\times\tau$) such that the union of these squares is not a square.

As an exercise: find out when $\tau\times\tau$ is indeed a topology (special case).